# Finding all NULL values from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, null

I am using mySQL (php) and trying to find all the rows in an entire table, including null values. Right now I am SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders, which does not include the NULL. I am confused on what to do next, I was thinking finding the NULL values seperately and then joining the two or something. However I cannot find the NULL for o_order-priority php tops reading it at 'order'...what do i do? There are 9 columns under the orders table.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Firstly, you need to be specific about your table structure and what "is null value" condition is. Secondly, you need to add your stored proc to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of count(*) use the column name like

```
Select count('name') from table
```

this will count all the rows whether null or with data

Answer (score 0):

If your table has 3 rows. A select count(*) --> 3 rows.
I think that you should try to count if a column of this table has a null value.
If you have a column named "order_text" and want to count the number of null value you can use:
Select count(*) from orders where order_text is null;

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(*)` will return all count of rows including `null`

see this example

```
Declare @percapHistPrev table
(
   id int 

)

insert into @percapHistPrev
select 1 union all
select null

select COUNT(*) from @percapHistPrev
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id
2

select COUNT(id) from @percapHistPrev

id
1
```